# Calling python script with arguments from a wrapper script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, shell

What I am trying to do is create a wrapper script, let's say `program1.py`, that calls `program2.py` and `program3.py` from `main()`. `program1.py`, `program2.py`, and `program3.py` all need to have their own arguments. What is the best way to go about creating this wrapper script? Should I prompt the user before running the `program2.py` script from `program1.py`'s main method?

Comment: Ideally your wrapper script would handle everything and collect all of the arguments required for the sub-programs

Comment: If you want to pass the same arguments to the 'wrapped' scripts, forward `sys.argv[1:]` to `subprocess.Popen()` (or other `subprocess` functions) when calling `program2.py` and `program3.py`. That is if you want to run them as subprocesses, you can just import them and let them share the current `sys` context as well.

Answer (score 1):

when passing arguments to Subprocess you need to pass it a list containing each word in the command you want to execute e.g.

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'program2.py', argv[1], argv[2]])
```

would execute program 2 with the arguments argv[1] and argv[2] of the wrapper process.

If `argv[1] = 'hello'` and `argv[2] = 'world'`

`python program2.py hello world`

would be executed.

Comment: What if I wanted to have something like --drop "collection_name" as an argument for program2.py? would i need to use argparse.ArgumentParser, add arguments, and use something like if args.collection_name == "example_collection" in the wrapper script and pass it to the second script?

Comment: While you dont have to use argparse, you could just collect the arguments with argv, it would would make your life a lot easier when dealing with more complex argument patterns.